# Encapsulate included functions?

Tags: php, scope, encapsulation

I'm trying to encapsulate an included file within a function. Nothing from the included file should be accessible outside the encapsulation function.

What I've found is that variables from the included file will be limited to the scope of the encapsulation function, but functions from the included file will be globally accessible.

index.php:

```
function encapsulate_this() {
    include 'some_file.php'; 
}

encapsulate_this();

echo say_hello();
echo $test_variable;
```

some_file.php:

```
$test_variable = "Hi!";

function say_hello() {
    return "Hello!";    
}
```

Output:

```
Hello!
```

In the above example echoing say_hello() will work, but $test_variable will not.

***How can I successfully encapsulate functions from the included file so they are not globally accessible?***

Answer (score 1):

All functions (and classes) are global in PHP, there's no such concept as "scope" for those things. I only see two options:

1. Name your functions and/or classes in a way so they won't conflict with other global things, namespaces can help a lot here. E.g. if you rigorously apply the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) naming standards to all files and all functions, it doesn't really matter whether functions are exposed globally or not, since their names cannot conflict.
2. Use *anonymous functions*, which is the only way functions can be scoped:

   ```
   $say_hello = function () {
       return 'Hello';
   };
   ```

Obviously, both depend on the included file to cooperate; if you're including a third party file which does not adhere to either standard, you're SOL.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider anonymous classes (php7+). In a class you can have `public`, `protected` and `private` members.

`public` members are accessible from outside the class.

`protected` members are accessible from inside the class and classes which inherit the class.

`private` members are only accessible from inside the class.

A little example:

some_file.php

```
$helloClass = new class('HelloWorld') {

    public function say_hello_public(){
        return "Hello!";
    }

    private function say_hello_private(){
        return "Hello!";
    }
};
```

index.php

```
function encapsulate_this() {
    include 'some_file.php'; 

    echo $helloClass->say_hello_public(); //Works because it's a public method.
    echo $helloClass->say_hello_private(); //Won't work because it's a private method.
}

encapsulate_this();

echo $helloClass->say_hello_public(); //Won't work outside scope
```

Comment: @deceze Yes true, but his question in bold is: `How can I successfully encapsulate functions from the included file so they are not globally accessible?` Doesn't say anything about a global class

Comment: "***Nothing*** from the included file should be accessible outside the encapsulation function." – Emphasis mine...